# VB script delete files creation date + exception

Tags: vbscript

i want to use a VB script to Delete files and folders older then 60 days.

How can i exclude specific folders in my script?

```
' Global FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Start at the root
DoFolder "H:\Werk\Testfolder"

' Recursive function
Sub DoFolder(strFolder)

With objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

    For Each objFile In .Files
        If objFile.DateCreated < Date - 60 Then objFile.Delete
    Next

    For Each objFolder In .SubFolders
        DoFolder objFolder.Path
    Next

    ' Checked every file and subfolder. If this folder is empty, remove it...
   If .Files.Count = 0 Then If .SubFolders.Count = 0 Then .Delete

End With

End Sub
```

I want to exclude the following:

**H:\Werk\Testfolder\Favorieten** 
and
**H:\Werk\Testfolder\OneNote-notitieblokken**

How can i  do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each objFolder In .SubFolders
    If objfolder.path <> "c:\whatever\whatever.ext" then
        DoFolder objFolder.Path
    End If
Next
```

Is how you do it.